# Multitenant module for vtiger

Tags: php, multi-tenant, vtiger

I want to create a multitenet module for vtiger. I've searched in google,
but I don't get a clear idea.

Is it possible to create different database and same files for each user? How can I select different data bases? I want to create a registration form and then after registration create a new database for that user. Then after login the user can get data from their own databases. Is it possible?any one please give me a clear idea.

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time - and one that is possible to answer in the Q&A format of the site. At the moment, it seems you are asking a number of questions and most of those are either opinion based or too broad to fit into the site format.

Comment: Hi there, yes it is possible to create a multitenent vTiger CRM not only module. For that you can have option for SAAS system which will be useful to handle multi tenancy for vTiger and also for user privileges files.

Or go to this link https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/54373/multi-tenant-or-multi-instances-with-vtiger-saas/p1